# PHP Command in script has different results than shell

Tags: php, bash, shell

I have the following lines in a BASH script:

```
ACTIONS_COMMAND="php -f $BASEDIR/scripts/activities.php < \"$SRC_DIR/%s/AndroidManifest.xml\""

printf -v ACTIONS_CMD "$ACTIONS_COMMAND" $FOLDER

$ACTIONS_CMD
```

This runs inside a loop to do the same operation to several Android applications.
When I echo the `$ACTIONS_CMD` and copy and paste the command, it produces the correct output, but the script itself starts PHP, but does not copy the `STDIN`. I know this because PHP hangs until I push `Ctrl-D` on the keyboard and then it complains there was no input.

I tried switching the PHP command to

```
ACTIONS_COMMAND="cat \"$SRC_DIR/%s/AndroidManifest.xml\" | php -f $BASEDIR/scripts/activities.php"
```

When the first file name is in quotes (which I think it should be for safety), I get

```
cat: "apps/app_name/AndroidManifest.xml": No such file or directory
cat: |: No such file or directory
cat: php: No such file or directory
cat: -f: No such file or directory
<?php
... REST OF PHP SCRIPT ...
```

and without the quotes, it just outputs to the terminal window.

If it matters, it is `GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)`.

Comment: add an `echo` just before the final constructed command to see what is generated and potentially any errors.

Comment: @MattWilliamson I did that and the command that resulted ran fine manually in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute programs with input/output redirection in a string like that.  It will attempt to use the pipe and angle characters and the file as input to the program you executed.

You need to pass that string to a shell in order to do the redirection.

One way to do that is:

```
bash -c "$ACTIONS_COMMAND"
```